# Android rearranging textviews error

Tags: android, textview

Lets say I have 4 text views. Two of them (tv1, tv3) contain static text, the text of the other two (tv2, tv4) changes dynamically during use of application.

Example:

TextView1:  textview2

TextView3:  textview4

My problem occures when I try to replace line 1 with line 2. I do this in graphical view by drag and drop. So basically what I want to get is:

TextView3:  textview4

TextView1:  textview2

However, that does not work as expected. I get:

TextView3:  textview2

TextView1:  textview4

Why this happens and how od I get around that problem?

Comment: Can you provide some code sample for us to better understand your issue?

Comment: We can't debug code that isn't posted.